# React images not loading

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working with Reactjs. I have a component where I have loaded images inside a map function

[image]

```
videos.map((clips) => {
  return (
    <tr key={clips._id}>
      <td>
        <div className="table-name-img">
          <div className="img-container">
              <img
                src={clips.videoThumbnailUrl}
                alt=""
                className="matchImageIcon"
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onLoad={() => {
                  console.log(55555);
                  setCount((count) => count + 1); // tried this way to rerender component but did not work
                }}
              />
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

But unfortunately it does not load the images. ***However when I change the tabs again come back then it loads***. What could be the issue here?

Update: I have a button from where I change the view i.e. from grid view to list view. By default it is grid view which loads the images perfectly but when I change it to list view (the below screenshot) it does not loads the images. I guess because the images are already loaded in the grid view so it is not loading it again???

Comment: check network tab in dev-tools to check if all the image requests to the server is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Plz, try it. Hope it would solve the problem.

`{videos.map((clips, index) => (...`

`<tr key={++index}>`

`<img src={clips?.videoThumbnailUrl}...`